# What's considered "low views" for the tumbleweed badge?

Tags: support, badges

To earn the tumbleweed badge, you must have "asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week"

What's considered 'low views'? It seems kinda like an arbitrary term to me. Is it a number based on any outside factors, such as traffic to arqade as a whole?

Comment: For me, the question that earned me the Tumbleweed badge currently has 23 views.

Comment: Mine has 206, so the limit seems to be pretty lenient.

Comment: @CruelCow you may have recieved the badge when the view count was lower.

Comment: I think [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/254144/108003) had less than 10 when I got mine.

Answer (score 1):

Views should be below 60 according to  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252304/2417043 . It also has comment that numbers are the same within entire network.